# What points should I add or sampling should I change to get a better georeference within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am working with an image that I need to georeference onto a base map.  I have already added two other images to the map with minimal issues.  They are not 100%, but they are good enough for this.

The problem is that when I try to line up the third, I can not get it anywhere close to actual area, and my `Residual (Pixels)` are very high.  I am open to any suggestions or ideas.

Base map that I am working off of.  The lines are images that I georeferenced prior.

[image]

This is my current attempts at georeferencing.  As you can see my Residuals are extremly high.  I have added more points in the past and had only marginal better results.

[image]

The final result of just using those three points.  As you can see it is not even close to where it should be.

[image]

Comment: You might try different transformation methods.

Comment: You should rotate your image by 180 deg prior to importing into the georeferencer. And, as @John suggests, use a different transformation as your image was taken from an offset shallow angle. Details of the transformation methods can be found here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#available-transformation-algorithms